# How to listen only to localhost on MongoDB

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb, node.js

[MongoDB Suggests](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication) that the easy way to handle security is to run it in a trusted environment, given that, "in such a configuration, one must be sure only trusted machines can access database TCP ports."

What would be the best approach for doing this? Is there a way for mongodb to natively only listen to localhost?

I'm using ubuntu 10.10

Comment: May I ask you to pick my answer as more correct?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Add the following line into `mongodb.conf`:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

As @Josh Rickard stated in comments: don't forget to restart the process after updating the config file:

```
service mongodb restart
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Don't forget to restart the process after updating the config file: `service mongodb restart`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll just leave here this link for those who will look for this info like me: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security/

Comment: Shouldn't this be a default in mongodb? Is it really true, that new mongodb installs are open to the world without any authentication?

Comment: @ThomasJensen I just installed mongodb from official Debian/Ubuntu source and it is set to localhost by default (now).

Comment: I had also thought mongo is set to localhost only on installation, and that you had to change the configuration if you wanted it otherwise. But I got a message from Digital Ocean saying that one of my servers had an open mongo instance. I can't access the mongo instance from its public IP, so I'm not sure how Digital Ocean accessed it. But they must have, since they only warned me about the instance I had a mongo server running.

Answer (score 35):

As Andreas mentioned in a round-about way:

```
mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I wonder why this so vital configuration option is not included among samples in configuration file.

Comment: To add this to the Windows service, you need to edit the registry entry at `[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MongoDB]`

Answer (score 5):

Note that although it didn't appear in the documentation last time I checked, you can also put this setting in the .conf file (vs. command line).

No setting = bind to all ips.

Answer (score 2):

No one mentioned the location of the `mongodb.conf` file which is `/etc/mongodb.conf`. Double check before running the following commands.

```
echo "bind_ip = 127.0.0.1" >> /etc/mongodb.conf
service mongodb restart
```

Comment: With new versions, it was renamed to `/etc/mongod.conf`

Answer (score 0):

This configuration appears to be default in 4.4 on Windows ...

`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.cfg`

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

... in case there are any other "poor, unfortunate souls" supporting or using it.