# Configure MongoDB to listen only on Unix Socket, not on any TCP port

Tags: mongodb, unix-socket

How to configure mongo DB to not to listen on any port, but only on unix domain socket?

Since my app and DB will run on same server, the two will communicate only via Unix domain sockets. To prevent any outside access to the mongoDB server I also want to disable it from listening on any TCP port.

Comment: Would the procedure in this question and answers, to listen only on localhost,   work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961177/how-to-listen-only-to-localhost-on-mongodb#7231757

Comment: yes, that is how I have configured it now. But would be great if it is possible to turn off listening on TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, setting net.bindIp to the name of the UNIX socket seems to work to disable the TCP/IP socket and keep the UNIX socket.

It also seems that MongoDB will always try to listen on the default socket (/tmp/mongodb-portnumber.sock) in addition to the configured socket name. To make MongoDB listen on only a single Unix socket, specify the default socket name a the bindIp:

```
net:
  bindIp: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```